# Wrapping a callback type with Swift protocols

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Let's say I'm dealing with a library I don't control and I'm trying to wrap a class that defines a callback type to decouple my code for testing purposes. Here's the class, inside module `AXSwift`:

```
public class Application {
  public typealias Callback = (element: UIElement) -> ()
  public func createObserver(callback: Callback) -> Observer? {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Here's the wrapper protocol for testing:

```
protocol UIElementProtocol {}
extension AXSwift.UIElement: UIElementProtocol {}

protocol ApplicationProtocol {
  func createObserver(callback: (element: UIElementProtocol) -> ()) -> Observer?
}
extension AXSwift.Application: ApplicationProtocol {}
```

I get **Type 'Application' does not conform to protocol 'ApplicationProtocol'**. If I change `UIElementProtocol` inside the ApplicationProtocol callback back to `UIElement`, it works. But `UIElement` conforms to `UIElementProtocol`, so why doesn't this work?

Second question: Is there a better way to design the library API to allow for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really simple, just implement the protocol in the extension with a method that calls the original method:

```
extension AXSwift.Application: ApplicationProtocol {
  func createObserver(callback: (element: UIElementProtocol) -> ()) -> Observer? {
    return createObserver(callback as Callback)
  }
}
```

Where `Callback` is the expected type. Apparently you have to be explicit about passing a general function type as a more specific type.